# Prove $\|\cdot\|_p$ and $\|\cdot \|_q$ aren't equivalent on $\ell^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$1 \leq p < q < \infty$

So we need to find something in $\ell ^p$ that gives different results in each of the two norms but I can't think of anything.

I could think of something that is n $\ell ^q$ and then show that they are not equivalent but nothing in $\ell ^p$

Comment: What do you know about the image of the inclusion $\iota_q^p \colon \ell^p \hookrightarrow \ell^q$?

Comment: After a certain point, $\ell^q$ makes the series converge faster than $\ell^p$. I am not too sure about the image of the inclusion.

Comment: Do you know that $\ell^p$ is a Banach space with the $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_p$-norm?

Comment: $$u_n = \frac{1}{n^{1/q+\epsilon}}$$

Comment: @user1952009 $\epsilon$ is small?

Comment: @user1952009 don't know how this works because if $u_n$ is in $\ell^p$ then we have for norm p: $1/n^{p/q + \epsilon}$ and for this to be in $\ell^p$, we must have that $p/q+ \epsilon >1$ so $\epsilon > 1-p/q$. Then this in norm q would be $1/n^{1+q\epsilon}$ which still converges...

Comment: no if $q > p \ge 1$ then for $\epsilon > 0$ small enough $(1/n^{1/q+\epsilon}) \in l^q $ and $\not\in l^p$. conversely, if $(v_n) \in l^p$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ and $C$ such that $v_n < C/n^{1/q+\epsilon}$ and $(v_n) \in l^q$

Comment: @user1952009 But we want to choose something that is in $l^p$, you just wrote that it is not an element of $l^p$..............

Comment: @user1952009 did u write $(1/q)+\epsilon $ or $1/(q+\epsilon)$ on the power of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the sequence (of sequences) $(x^{(n)})_n\in \left(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\right)^{\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $x^{(n)}_k =\frac{1}{k^{\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{n}}}$.

- For any $n$, you have $$\lVert x^{(n)} \rVert_p = \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1+\frac{p}{n}}} \right)^{1/p}< \infty$$
  and
  $$\lVert x^{(n)} \rVert_q = \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{\frac{q}{p}+\frac{q}{n}}} \right)^{1/q}< \infty$$ (since $\frac{q}{p} > 1$) so $(x^{(n)})_n\in \ell_p^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $(x^{(n)})_n\in \ell_q^{\mathbb{N}}$.
- However, you can check that $(x^{(n)})_n$ converges in $\ell_q$, but not in $\ell_p$.${}^{(\dagger)}$ So the two norms cannot be equivalent, since otherwise $(x^{(n)})_n$ would have the same nature under both norms $\lVert\cdot\rVert_q$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_p$.

$(\dagger)$ This is because, where $n\to \infty$, the limit of $(x^{(n)})_n$ can only be the pointwise limit $x\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ defined by $x_k = \frac{1}{k^{\frac{1}{p}}}$. But $x\in\ell^q$, yet not in $x\in\ell^p$.

Comment: What do symbols like $\ell_p^{\mathbb N}$ mean?

Comment: $X^\mathbb{N}$ means "a sequence of elements from $X$." So here, it is a sequence of (sequences in $\ell_p$).

Comment: Does $\ell^p$ mean the same thing as $\ell_p$?

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, inconsistency of notation on my behalf.